# FlatList does not show the API result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I'm just training how to consume apis in react-native with useEffects and in console.log () returns the results, but in the view it doesn't show, I think it's the keyExtractor or not ...

```
const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=2';

const Detalhes = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((results) => {
        setData(results);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(results);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#5500dc" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>
          Error...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and this is the code with FlatList that should be returned in View and as said, I can see the result in console.log (react native debug)

```
<SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.first}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
         <View style={styles.metaInfo}>
           <Text style={styles.text}>
             {`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
           </Text>
         </View>
        )}
     />
 </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see again `console.log(results)`. Api response is an object `{ results, info }`, not an array. The results property of results is array.

Replace `setData(results);` by `setData(results.results);` to resolve your problem.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving `name` in your `keyExtractor` which could be same repeat so It won't work. Try changing `keyExtractor` like below to provide unique index for each item

```
keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
```